# Can a flash loan used to flash attack a smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, voting, flash-loans, flashbots

I am new to flash loans. Let us say I have smart contract where people vote. Your voting power on this contract is based on how many token x you have. The votes are yes and no and the vote with more than 50% wins.

During voting, can an attacker take a flash loan and cast their vote to manipulate the results to what they want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Moreover that technique was already used against MakerDao, read https://forum.makerdao.com/t/urgent-flash-loans-and-securing-the-maker-protocol/4901.

It can be fixed by requiring funds to be locked for a period of time longer than a block.

Comment: Is it possible to take multiple flash loans on multiple blocks and successfully run the attack?

Comment: @YulePale A flash loan has to be returned immediately it cannot last longer than a single transaction. To jump over a block you need a regular loan that will require a collateral.